# How to I make two <section> tags have no gap in-between them

Tags: html, css

My assignment requires me to have two  tags on top of each other. but there is this annoying gap between the two that I would like to get rid of. Between the gap is the background image that does not look good with the rest of the website. Thanks to everyone that can help me.

```css
#profileSection {
  margin-top: 300px;
  padding-right: 400px;
  padding-left: 400px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%:
}

#profileTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#profileDesc {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#profilePic {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#mainTitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

#skillsSection {
  padding-right: 400px;
  padding-left: 400px;
  background-color: #181818;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="profileSection">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-8 col-md-12">
        <h1 id="profileTitle">About Me</h1>
        <p id="profileDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu justo quam. Donec et magna ante. Integer ullamcorper sit amet erat a pharetra. Aliquam euismod, mauris sit amet ultricies sodales, purus enim dictum dui, in mattis quam ex non
          neque. Suspendisse quis tristique tellus. Vestibulum dignissim eros non arcu sollicitudin, a auctor augue faucibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris sit amet dui pulvinar, interdum
          arcu et, consequat dui. Fusce velit elit, molestie sed tincidunt eget, ornare in nibh. Nunc aliquet dapibus odio sit amet varius. Suspendisse nec ipsum odio. Morbi iaculis velit eget mi tristique dignissim. Donec rutrum gravida ex, vel molestie
          sapien condimentum quis. Morbi convallis placerat eros ac volutpat.</p>
        <img id="profilePic" src="pics/profilePicture.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div id="skillsSection">
    <h1 id="skillsTitle">Skills</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks to anyone that can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove/override the top margin of the heading.

```
#skillsTitle {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It was so simple I don't know how I didn't Think of that! Thank you so much!